# Docker WORKDIR path issues

Tags: docker

After the FROM statement in my Dockerfile, the first commands I have are:

```
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY . /home/app
```

I thought what this would do this create an `/app` directory in my filesystem's `/home` and copy the files there. Instead it just treats it as a relative path, creating a `/home/app` in the image's default location. Like `/var/lib/docker/whatever/whatever/home/app`. Am I missing something or am I just misunderstanding what WORKDIR does?

Comment: That doesn’t sound right. Could you post a [mcve] including both a (complete) Dockerfile and how you check where things end up?

Comment: Filesystems in Docker are normally completely isolated from the host.  In the isolated container filesystem, this should create a directory `/home/app`.  A Dockerfile can never create a directory on the host.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to say : "in my container's filesystem"

WORKDIR is used to set the working directory for the next commands.
That means /home/app already exist and become the working directory for your next commands RUN, COPY, ENTRYPOINT, etc...
It changes the default working directory who comes with the images downloaded with FROM.

Then COPY . /home/app will copy all the files from the repertory where you re executing your build in /home/app.

You can check the results with docker exec -it <my_containers> /bin/bash after docker run

Hope this help ?